# mysql NOT IN QUERY optimize

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables named as:

1. table_product
2. table_user_ownned_auction

#### table_product

```
specific_product_id      astatus  ... 
(primary_key,autoinc)
--------------------------------------
1                        APAST    ...
2                        ALIVE    ...
3                        ALIVE    ...
4                        APAST    ... 
5                        APAST    ...
```

#### table_user_ownned_auction

```
own_id     specific_product_id   details   
----------------------------------------
1                  1               XXXX
2                  5               XXXX
```

I need to select `atatus = APAST`, and not in table 2.
Which means, in above structure table1 has 3 APAST status (1,4,5). But in table 2  specific_product_id (1,5) only stored so i need to select specific_product_id = 4

I used this query

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table_product 
   WHERE astatus = 'APAST' 
     AND specific_product_id NOT IN (SELECT specific_product_id 
                                       FROM table_user_ownned_auction )
```

...which takes this long:

> Query took 115.1039 sec

...to execute.

#### EXPLAIN PLAN

[image]

How can i optimize it or any other way to select what i want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a index on the `table_user_ownned_auction` table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_user_ownned_auction ADD KEY(specific_product_id)
```

Also, try using a `non-exists` join:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM table_product p
    LEFT JOIN table_user_ownned_auction l
      ON p.specific_product_id = l.specific_product_id
WHERE p.astatus = 'APAST' 
    AND l.specific_product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: @gowri: That can also be because the query plan has been cached

Comment: use exact field names instead of `SELECT *`

Answer (score 14):

#### Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM TABLE_PRODUCT p
 WHERE p.astatus = 'APAST' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM TABLE_USER_OWNED_AUCTION uoa
                    WHERE uoa.specific_product_id = p.specific_product_id)
```

#### Using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`

```
   SELECT p.* 
     FROM TABLE_PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN TABLE_USER_OWNED_AUCTION uoa ON uoa.specific_product_id = p.specific_product_id
    WHERE p.astatus = 'APAST' 
      AND uoa.own_id IS NULL
```

#### Explanation

The most optimal query can be determined by if the columns compared between the two tables are NULLable (IE: if the values of `specific_product_id` in either table can be `NULL`).

- If [nullable, `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` is the best choice in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)
- If [NOT nullable, `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the best choice in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

#### Addendum

Once the optimal query has been determined, take a look at [creating indexes (possibly covering indexes)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for at least:

- `specific_product_id`
- `TABLE_PRODUCT.astatus`

Comment: I liked your solution. I am learning mysql. Could you please explain me what will be selected in the subquery in NOT EXISTS(..) when uoa.specific_product_id != p.specific_product_id

Comment: @Sandeep: `NOT` performs the reversal, to change `uoa.specific_product_id = p.specific_product_id` into `uoa.specific_product_id != p.specific_product_id`.

Comment: There is a typo at Addendum One -> Once.

Comment: I read your referenced [article](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) and it seems that there is no performance difference between `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` and `NOT IN`. So you could conclude that you could just always use `NOT IN` and you are always covered. Quote for comparing both in article: "The algorithms are in fact the same in fact and the queries complete in same time."