# mysql not using indexes when "not in" statement is present

Tags: mysql

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `read` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `direction` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `one` (`to`,`direction`,`from`,`id`),
  KEY `two` (`from`,`direction`,`to`,`id`),
  KEY `three` (`read`,`direction`,`to`),
  KEY `four` (`read`,`direction`,`from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a strange issue. Please have a look at the following query:

```
select test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction from test 
where (

    (test.to = 244975 and test.direction <> 2 and test.direction <> 3 and 
        (
        (test.from = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR 
        (test.from = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.from = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.from = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.from = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.from = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.from = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.from = 244690 and test.id > 5338467) 
        )

    )

    or 

    (test.from = 244975 and test.direction <> 1 and test.direction <> 3 and 
        (
        (test.to = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR
        (test.to = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.to = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.to = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.to = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.to = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.to = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.to = 244690 and test.id > 5338467)
        )
    )

    or 

    (test.read <> 1 and test.direction <> 3 and test.direction <> 2 and test.to = 244975  and test.from not in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)

    )

    or

    (test.read <> 1 and test.direction = 2 and test.from = 244975 and test.to not in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)

    )


     )



     order by test.id;
```

If I do an explain on this query, it goes through all the rows:

```
1   SIMPLE  test    index   PRIMARY,one,two,three,four  PRIMARY 4       1440596 Using where
```

If I remove both the "not in" statements, then it works fine:

```
select test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction from test 
where (

    (test.to = 244975 and test.direction <> 2 and test.direction <> 3 and 
        (
        (test.from = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR 
        (test.from = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.from = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.from = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.from = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.from = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.from = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.from = 244690 and test.id > 5338467) 
        )

    )

    or 

    (test.from = 244975 and test.direction <> 1 and test.direction <> 3 and 
        (
        (test.to = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR
        (test.to = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.to = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.to = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.to = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.to = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.to = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.to = 244690 and test.id > 5338467)
        )
    )

    or 

    (test.read <> 1 and test.direction <> 3 and test.direction <> 2 and test.to = 244975 

    )

    or

    (test.read <> 1 and test.direction = 2 and test.from = 244975 

    )


     )



     order by test.id;
```

Now the explain query returns:

```
1   SIMPLE  test    index_merge PRIMARY,one,two,three,four  one,two 5,5     30  Using sort_union(one,two); Using where; Using filesort
```

I am not sure why it does not work right. What am I missing in the indexes?

Comment: How big is your table? And could you try using `FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)` to see if there is a performance gain?

Comment: Have you tried using not_exists()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120100/mysql-not-in-query-optimize

Comment: @mani about 4 million records

Comment: @Alec are the values `204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690` different every time the query executes, or constant? If different, how often does the get executed?

Comment: This is a very unusual query to be running repeatedly. How did you end up here? Perhaps there is another data storage approach that could ease the solution.

Comment: How many records do you get back after using `NOT IN` condition? By the glimpse of it, your `NOT IN` short-circuits your other "big" `OR` conditions, which leaves you with last 2 `OR` conditions which are tiny. Having used `direction` which appears to have low cardinality, that forces MySQL to scan all the rows to satisfy your 2 remaining `OR` conditions. That's my 2 cents, I know it doesn't help really but your `where` conditions are really, really ugly :)

Comment: @Bohemian the values change every time

Comment: @alec it's too late to answer now, after the bounty has ended, if you want better answers. You should monitor the site for comments/questions, especially if there's a bounty in play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure why it does not work right. What am I missing in the indexes?

I'm pretty sure the query planner is working perfectly, you're not missing anything in the indexes that would help in this case. The query planner decided that it would be faster to use a different index because the two queries are very different.

We can make the optimizer use a union of the indexes for us which will make it considerably faster. You can keep the `not in` and not change any of the `or` statements. I ran some basic benchmarks of the method I used against the union method. Caveats apply because your DB configuration may be vastly different than mine. Running the query a 1000 times and doing this 3 times I took the best time for each query...

**Optimized Query shown below**

```
real    0m15.410s
user    0m6.681s
sys 0m2.641s
```

**Re-Written as a set of unions**

```
real    0m17.747s
user    0m6.798s
sys 0m2.812s
```

**Think like the optimizer and work with less data**

The following SQL is several orders of magnitude faster in tests on a ~4 million row database. The key change is the following line

```
(select * from test where test.from_ in (244975, 204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690) or test.to_ in (244975, 204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)) as test
```

This one line is vastly reducing the dataset that mysql needs to work on because we're using `in` instead of `not in`. This is the new query, I've tried not to change the original query too much.

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE test.id, test.from_, test.to_, test.message, test.sent, test.read_, test.direction 
from (select * from test where test.from_ in (244975, 204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690) or test.to_ in (244975, 204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)) as test 
where (
  (test.to_ = 244975 and test.direction <> 2 and test.direction <> 3 and test.from_ in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690) and 
        (   
        (test.from_ = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR  
        (test.from_ = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.from_ = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.from_ = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.from_ = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.from_ = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.from_ = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.from_ = 244690 and test.id > 5338467) 
        )   
    )   
    or  
    (test.from_ = 244975 and test.direction <> 1 and test.direction <> 3 and test.to_ in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690) and 
        (   
        (test.to_ = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR
        (test.to_ = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.to_ = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.to_ = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.to_ = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.to_ = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.to_ = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.to_ = 244690 and test.id > 5338467)
        ))  
    or  
    (test.read_ <> 1 and test.direction <> 2 and test.direction <> 3 and test.to_ = 244975  and test.from_ not in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690))
    or  
    (test.read_ <> 1 and test.direction = 2 and test.from_ = 244975 and test.to_ not in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690))
     )   
     order by test.id;
```

The explain plan for this looks very different...

```
mysql> \. sql_fixed.sql
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 226
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: test
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: one,two
          key: two,one
      key_len: 4,4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 226
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using sort_union(two,one); Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

The optimizer being smart immediately can see that it doesn't need most of the data because up front we've told it to use an `IN` statement with a few keys. Most query optimizers attach a high cost to disk accesses so anything that reduces this it typically preferred by the optimizer.

**NOT IN vs IN**

`not in` and `in` are very different. The difference between these in this case is access pattern, do I need the data temporarily or as part of the result set. When you use `not in` with a few keys and the index holds millions of keys it might need to read lots of records if the data is part of the result set. Even when using indexes `not in` can be reading millions of records from disk... `in` with a few keys and these are the keys you need is asking to find and use a small subset. The two access patterns are very different. The following example might help make this clear...

```
1. I don't want these 10 items from a 1,000,000 records I need the other 999,990, this reads the whole index.
2. I only want these 10 from a 1,000,000 records. This might only require one disk seek.
```

Number 2 is faster because the of the access pattern ie I found the 10 I need, Nunmber 1. may need to read a million records.

MySQL's query optimizer is seeing this ie the last two OR statements are asking for large subsets of data from either the table or the index ie case 1. above. Seeing that and the fact that it needed to use the primary key anyway the optimizer decided it would be quicker to use the primary key.

When you remove the `not in` things change ie now the query planner can use the indexes because in the other two `or` clauses they're in effect `get me the few from the many` and it performs an index_merge on the two keys that share a `to` and a `from` column along with the `id`.

To see what I mean don't remove the 'not in' part of the query, change it to `in` to see what happens, on my machine the query plan changed to use a range index.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you want some more ideas on how to tune the above there are better indexes you can use. You won't gain much but if the optimizer is choosing them there's a high likelihood they're more optimal. They're smaller than the current indexes and this might be the biggest  gain.

Answer (score 4):

If your mySQL version less then 5.0.7, the mysql issue can be reason

Have a look this ticket in MySQL bug tracking https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10561

Answer (score 4):

Mixing `AND` and `OR` would often cause weird query plan on MySQL, in my experience. I don't have enough data on the table to test, but I would try rewriting your query using `UNION ALL`. After all, `OR` in `WHERE` is basically `UNION`.

The idea is to break it down on smaller conditions so MySQL can use different index optimized for each part as opposed to jamming all together.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction
FROM
    test 
WHERE
    test.to = 244975
    AND test.direction <> 2
    AND test.direction <> 3
    AND (
        (test.from = 204177 AND test.id > 5341203) OR 
        (test.from = 214518 AND test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.from = 231429 AND test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.from = 242739 AND test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.from = 243834 AND test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.from = 244354 AND test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.from = 244644 AND test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.from = 244690 AND test.id > 5338467) 
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction
FROM
    test 
WHERE
    test.from = 244975
    AND test.direction <> 1
    AND test.direction <> 3
    AND (
        (test.to = 204177 and test.id > 5341203) OR
        (test.to = 214518 and test.id > 5336549) OR
        (test.to = 231429 and test.id > 5338284) OR
        (test.to = 242739 and test.id > 5339541) OR
        (test.to = 243834 and test.id > 5340438) OR
        (test.to = 244354 and test.id > 5337489) OR
        (test.to = 244644 and test.id > 5338572) OR
        (test.to = 244690 and test.id > 5338467)
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction
FROM
    test 
WHERE
    test.read <> 1
    AND test.direction <> 3
    AND test.direction <> 2
    AND test.to = 244975
    AND test.from NOT IN (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction
FROM
    test 
WHERE
    test.read <> 1
    AND test.direction = 2
    AND test.from = 244975
    AND test.to NOT IN (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)
) test ORDER BY test.id
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be good to have a dump of sample data to test with, but I created some of my own anyway. Next I split each of the four outer OR conditions into sub-queries, UNIONed them, and moved the ordering to the final result set.

I've had issues with indexes when using complex WHERE clauses and to me it looks like you have a chat/messaging app and are attempting to get messages to and from a particular user in a single query. Personally, I'd split these into individual queries to simplify the code/queries.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT test.id, test.from, test.to, test.message, test.sent, test.read, test.direction
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  WHERE test.to = 244975
    AND test.direction not in (2,3)
    AND (
      (test.from = 204177 AND test.id > 5341203)
      OR (test.from = 214518 AND test.id > 5336549)
      OR (test.from = 231429 AND test.id > 5338284)
      OR (test.from = 242739 AND test.id > 5339541)
      OR (test.from = 243834 AND test.id > 5340438)
      OR (test.from = 244354 AND test.id > 5337489)
      OR (test.from = 244644 AND test.id > 5338572)
      OR (test.from = 244690 AND test.id > 5338467)
    )
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  WHERE test.from = 244975
    AND test.direction not in (1,3)
    AND (
      (test.to = 204177 AND test.id > 5341203)
      OR (test.to = 214518 AND test.id > 5336549)
      OR (test.to = 231429 AND test.id > 5338284)
      OR (test.to = 242739 AND test.id > 5339541)
      OR (test.to = 243834 AND test.id > 5340438)
      OR (test.to = 244354 AND test.id > 5337489)
      OR (test.to = 244644 AND test.id > 5338572)
      OR (test.to = 244690 AND test.id > 5338467)
    )
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  WHERE test.read != 1
    AND test.direction not in (2,3)
    AND test.to = 244975
    AND test.from not in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  WHERE test.read != 1
    AND test.direction = 2
    AND test.from = 244975
    AND test.to not in (204177, 214518, 231429, 242739, 243834, 244354, 244644, 244690)
) test
ORDER BY test.id;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to the additional level of nesting / complexity the `in` condition on an additional column adds to your where clause.

The [index merge union sort](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html) your 2nd query uses converts the where clause into a set of [range conditions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html) combined by `OR`.

Each value you compare using `in` counts as another range predicate, so adding the two `in`conditions with 8 values each to your first query adds 64 more predicates.

As the number of predicates goes up, at some point the optimizer decides it is faster to just scan the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this

```
select  a.id, a.from, a.to, a.message, a.sent,
        a.read, a.direction
    from  ( ( SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.to   = 244975 ) UNION DISTINCT
            ( SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.from = 244975 ) ) a
    where ...  -- but change `test` to `a`
```

Assuming the subquery has a lot fewer rows than `test`, this may work faster.

Now, to use "lazy evaluation" to speed it up more:

```
select  a.id, a.from, a.to, a.message, a.sent,
        a.read, a.direction
    from  ( ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE test.to   = 244975 ) UNION DISTINCT
            ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE test.from = 244975 ) ) b  -- Note `b`
    JOIN test AS a  USING(id)   -- added
    where ...  -- but change `test` to `a`
```

This *may* help because it is not lugging around all the columns as long.

This last version needs only

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)
INDEX(from, id)
INDEX(to,   id)
```

Comment: Yes.  It's been a while.  (You have a nasty query here.  The real solution may involve redesigning the schema.)

Comment: I know it's nasty but I think the OP knows that as well, he has enough rep that I assume he knows what he's doing. The question asks why the `not in` is causing issues and I tried to address that. The query/schema can be addressed quite a few ways. I'll be back on in a few hours, it's a small world. I was in ysports and loved it there.

Comment: @Harry yes, aware of the nasty query :(

Comment: As already mentioned, `OR` is a sever killer -- it effectively leads to table scans.  `NOT IN ( SELECT ...)` is a lot worse than `NOT IN ( 1,2,3 )` because of repeated calls to the subquery.